Где должна стоять запятая (или две) при пояснительной вставке?
Если наполнить два стакана водой (?) - один полностью, а другой наполовину (?) - то у вас получится полтора стакана воды.

Я бы записала так:
Если наполнить два стакана водой — один полностью, а другой наполовину, — то у вас получится полтора стакана воды.
Образец у Розенталя:
Когда он начинает сомневаться в себе — а это с ним изредка происходит, — он пытается стать рационалистом — вставное предложение примыкает к предшествующей придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения, и запятая ставится после всей конструкции.

У вас первое предложение поясняется. После него и ставите длинное тире. Затем у вас это предложение заканчивается, следует запятая, закрывающая главное предложение. Второго длинного тире нет, потому что главное предложение закончилось.
За запятой следует придаточное предложение.
Место длинного тире определяется тем, какое из двух предложений оно уточняет ответом на вопрос "в каком объёме?". Очевидно, что то, где глагол "наполнить".
